# Is it possible maintain offline API documentation in tablet/iPad(android)?

Tags: ipad, tablet, tablet-pc

I would like to maintain JAVA API & Angular API in my tablet for convenience. is it possible with android 4.1.2 version? help me to find the way.

Comment: You could try downloading the HTML docs from the java site, and then viewing them with https://itunes.apple.com/app/documents-by-readdle/id364901807?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4  -- here's the download link for the Java API: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html

Comment: i didn't get answer. Is it possible to maintain angular API & JAVA API documentation in iPad/tablet with android version